# Tic Tac Toe game: Printing the value of a class object inside a list

Tags: python, oop, tic-tac-toe

I have to design a simple tic tac toe game for an assignment. The instructions are to make a Case (for the square) class initiated with an "occupe" variable that starts with ' ' and will be filled with an 'X' if it's player's 1 turn and an 'O' if it's player's 2 turn.

Then I have to build a class Terrain (for the board) which inherits the Case and constructs a grid (the "grille") with a list of nine Case objects.

But then I just can't figure out how to print the content of the squares and not the method itself.

Is my 'Case' class badly defined?

Here is the code:

```
class Case: 
  def __init__(self):
    self.occupe = ' '
  def jouer1(self):
    if self.occupe == ' ':
       self.occupe = 'O'   
    else:
      print('La case est déjà occupée')
  def jouer2(self):
    if self.occupe == ' ':
      self.occupe = 'X' 
    else:
      print('La case est déjà occupée')
  def __str__(self):
    return self.occupe.__str__() 

class Terrain(Case): 
  def __init__(self): 
    b = [Case(),Case(),Case(),Case(),Case(),Case(),Case(),Case(),Case()]
    self.grille = b
    self.tour = 1  
  def __str__(self):
        return self.grille[0].__str__() + '|' + self.grille[1].__str__() 
        + '|' + self.grille[2].__str__() + '|' + '\n' 
        + self.grille[3].__str__() + '|' + self.grille[4].__str__() + '|' 
        + self.grille[5].__str__() + '|' + '\n' 
        + self.grille[6].__str__() + '|' + self.grille[7].__str__() + '|' 
        + self.grille[8].__str__() + '|' + '\n'    
  def jouer(self, n= range(0,8)):
    if self.tour == 1:
      self.grille[n] = self.grille[n].jouer1
      self.tour = self.tour +1
    if self.tour == 2:
      self.grille[n] == 'X'
      self.tour = self.tour - 1 
T1 = Terrain()
T1.jouer(0)
print(T1)
```

The result:

```
<bound method Case.jouer1 of <__main__.Case object at 0x7f27c7d0fc90>>| | |
```

I expected to get an "X" in the print results

Comment: Copy the code and output text into your question instead of the image.

Comment: Ah, yes that's done

Comment: At the very least, don't call `__str__` explicitly; use `str(self.grille[0])` instead. However, it's simpler (and more efficient) to generate a single string using f-strings instead. `return f'{self.grille[0]} | {self.grille[1]} | self.grille[2] |\n...'`.

Comment: That's the value. In `__str__` you return `return self.grille[0].__str__()` (which should be `return str(self.grille[0])` BTW). You define this value in `jouer` with `self.grille[n] = self.grille[n].jouer1`. Maybe you wanted `self.grille[n] = self.grille[n].jouer1()`.

Comment: You have to *call* `jouer1`: `self.grille[n] = self.grille[n].jouer1()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the issues:

- The `return` statement in the `__str__` method of `Terrain` is split over multiple lines, but is not interpreted like that. You should either wrap that expression in parentheses or use a line continuation character (`\`) at each line wrap.
- Parentheses are missing after `grille[n].jouer1`, so the function is never called.
- `grille[n].jouer1()` does not return a value, so it should not be assigned to anything, otherwise you put `None` in your grid. Moreover, that method *already* assigns the correct character to that entry in the grid, so it should not happen here.
- In `jouer`, the second `if` should really be an `else`, as otherwise it will also execute if the first `if` block was executed (as it increments `self.tour`)
- `self.grille[n] == 'X'` is wrong. That grid should consist of `Case` instances, and not be overwritten. What needs to be set is an *attribute* of the `Case` instance at that index. This is what the `jouer2` method does, so call it.
- `n=range(0,8)` is not doing what you intended. I guess you wanted to indicate what the limits are for this parameter, but instead it defines a *default* value, which is a `range` object. As your code expects it to be a number, you should omit this.

The above are the errors/mistakes in your code. But there are other things you should modify:

- You should not call the `__str__` method explicitly, but (if needed) call the `str()` function.
- Don't put a number in a method name, like you have `jouer1` and `jouer2`, which leads to code repetition. Instead pass that number as argument to a method that treats it accordingly.
- The expression in your second `__str__` method (which spans several lines) can be reduced by using the power of loops, list comprehension syntax and the `join` method.
- I would also replace the 9 `Case()` calls with list comprehension.
- The `if` constructs in the `jouer` method can be replaced by statements which work correctly for both cases of `self.tour`

Here is how the resulting code could look:

```
class Case: 
  def __init__(self):
    self.occupe = ' '

  def jouer(self, tour):  # Don't put number in method name; pass it as argument
    if self.occupe == ' ':
       self.occupe = ' OX'[tour]  # Dynamically determine the character
    else:
       print('La case est déjà occupée')
                
  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.occupe)  # Call str, not __str__ 


class Terrain(Case): 
  def __init__(self): 
    self.grille = [Case() for _ in range(9)]  # List comprehension
    self.tour = 1  
      
  def __str__(self):
    # no need to call __str__, but call str(). Use comprehension & join
    return "\n".join("|".join(map(str, self.grille[i*3:i*3+3])) for i in range(3))
      
  def jouer(self, n):  # Not default value as range
    self.grille[n].jouer(self.tour)  # Call - don't assign
    self.tour = 3 - self.tour  # Toggle


T1 = Terrain()
T1.jouer(0)
T1.jouer(4)
T1.jouer(3)
print(T1)
```